# 503 Error while Running JMeter for Thread 400,Is it Because of Server issues?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

[image]

Getting 503 Error while Running the JMeter for the Thread User 400,Is it Because of Server issues.? When I run the thread group for 100 user with ramp up period 25 seconds then it will be working fine but for the user 400 users its giving 503 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you don't experience any issues with 100 users and have issues with 400 users most probably it's a server issue connected with the overload so congratulations on finding the [bottleneck](https://www.perfecto.io/detecting-bottlenecks-performance-testing/).

You can either report it as is or perform a little bit deeper investigation in order to find the cause, suggested steps:

1. Instead of kicking off 400 users at once try increasing the load gradually at the same time looking at [Response Times vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/) and [Transaction Throughput vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionThroughputVsThreads/) charts. Ideally response time should remain the same and throughput should be growing as the number of threads increase. When response time starts increasing and throughput starts decreasing it indicates the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) and at this stage you can state that this is the maximum number of users your application can support
2. Check your application logs and configuration as it might be not properly tuned for the high loads, you can use [15 Simple ASP.NET Performance Tuning Tips](https://stackify.com/asp-net-performance-tuning/) as a reference or look for a similar guide for your application technology stack
3. Ensure that your application has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, etc. as it might be the case that it's basically a lack of resources, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
4. Repeat your test with [profiler tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) in place, this way you will be able to localize the problem and state where is the problematic piece of code or inefficient algo lives.

Answer (score 0):

If server isn't down/restarted, then yes, [503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) indicate overload

> Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded

You need to find what stop server from serving 400 concurrent requests/users

Notice that if you are testing on a test environment which isn't equal/similar to production environment, it may not reflect the load that production server can endure

Comment: I'm checking in the Production server and when i increase the Ramp Period then it is working fine .. what will be the issues ,I m not able to analyze .

Comment: @adarshab your server has limit of concurrent users (at the same time), increasing ramp period spreads the users requests

Comment: ,How can I check the Limit  of concurrent users in the server..

Comment: @adarshab this is what your test did, you reached the limit